# „Gut tun“ oder „guttun“

Tags: verb, spelling, separable-verb, reformed-orthography

Ich lerne die Verben mit Dativ-Ergänzung, und ich interessierte mich besonders für das Verb *gut tun* auf [dieser Seite](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=40#liste_dativ_erg), aber eine Sache kapierte ich nicht: Warum wird das Verb auf [*Duden online*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/guttun) *guttun* geschrieben, und nicht *gut tun*? Auf *mein-deutschbuch.de* gibt es ein Beispiel:

> Eine Seereise wird dir gut tun.

Laut *Duden online* ist es korrekt zu schreiben:

> Eine Seereise wird dir guttun.

Wie ist die richtige Schreibung?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ja, laut Duden soll "guttun" geschrieben werden.

Laut dessen [Rechtschreibregel 47](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/getrennt-und-zusammenschreibung#K47) wird diese sogenannte *trennbare* oder *unfeste Zusammensetzung* aus Verb und Präposition, Adjektiv, Adverb oder Substantiv "im Infinitiv, in den beiden Partizipien sowie bei Endstellung im Nebensatz zusammengeschrieben". Weitere Informationen zur Getrennt- und Zusammenschreibung von Wortgruppen mit Verben finden Sie dort auch unter den Regeln 48 bis 56.

Diese Regelung beruht auf der Annahme, dass es sich bei diesen Wörtern jeweils um *ein* Wort, nicht um mehrere, handelt.

Das wird vielleicht nachvollziehbar mit Blick auf die unter Regel 48 aufgeführten Fälle, in denen es um getrennt geschriebene Wortgruppen geht, die trennbaren Zusammensetzungen ähnlich sind, z. B.:

> - Die Richterin hat ihn freigesprochen.
>
> Aber: Sie hat frei gesprochen (ohne Manuskript).

Answer (score 5):

Die Regeln für Getrennt- und Zusammenschreibung sind recht kompliziert und haben sich mehrfach geändert. Wie der aktuelle Duden (und auch Wahrig) aber richtig sagen, wird *guttun* heute als ein Wort geschrieben, und so war es auch die meiste Zeit der vergangenen hundert Jahre. Die erste Fassung der Rechtschreibreform, gültig (mit Einschränkungen) von 1996 bis 2006, sah allerdings die Getrenntschreibung *gut tun* vor. Laut Angabe im Seitenfuß wurde mein-deutschbuch.de 2007 veröffentlicht; möglicherweise basiert es auf Material, das einige Jahre vorher geschrieben wurde, und folgt deshalb in diesem Punkt der damals vorübergehend gültigen Schreibweise. Es könnte auch schlicht ein Fehler sein.

---

Die heutige Schreibweise ergibt sich aus § 34 (2.2) der [*Amtlichen Regelung* von 2006](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf):

> Es wird zusammengeschrieben, wenn der adjektivische Bestandteil zusammen mit dem verbalen Bestandteil eine neue, idiomatisierte Gesamtbedeutung bildet, die nicht auf der Basis der Bedeutungen der einzelnen Teile bestimmt werden kann, zum Beispiel: *krankschreiben*, *freisprechen*, (…)

Dies entspricht auch der alten Rechtschreibung; hier die entsprechende Regel 205 aus der 20. Auflage des Rechtschreib-Duden von 1991 (letzte Fassung vor der Reform):

> Verbindungen mit einem Verb als zweitem Glied schreibt man in der Regel dann zusammen, wenn durch die Verbindung ein neuer Begriff entsteht, den die bloße Nebeneinanderstellung nicht ausdrückt.

Hingegen hob die *Amtliche Regelung* von 1996 in § 34 (2.2) darauf ab, ob der erste Bestandteil erweiterbar (außer durch *nicht*) oder steigerbar ist; in diesem Fall, ausgeführt in § 34 E3 (3), galt Getrenntschreibung. Das traf auf *gut tun* zu, weil das *gut* erweiterbar ist: *Bei der Hitze tut eine Dusche wahnsinnig gut.* Die starke Tendenz der ursprünglichen Reform zur Getrenntschreibung war einer ihrer umstrittensten Punkte.

Comment: Ist es sicher auch in diesem Fall so? "krankschreiben" ist ja recht eindeutig; ich bin zuhause und kuriere mich auch - ich bin nicht dabei, etwas zu schreiben, während ich krank bin. Die Seereise tut mir gut - Die Seereise wird mir gut tun - Die Seereise wird mir guttun. Hier haben beide Varianten doch noch dieselbe Intention?

Comment: @wernersbacher: Ich würde sagen, es gibt gar keine zweite Variante. Was soll *Es tut mir gut/schlecht/grün/hohl* in nicht übertragenem Sinn denn bedeuten?

Comment: vermutlich hast du Recht. Dann würde es "Das tut mir gut" gar nicht geben, inhaltlich gesehen. Oder wie war das gemeint?

Comment: Ja, es gibt nur (noch) die feste Fügung mit eigenständiger Bedeutung.

Answer (score -1):

Beides ist richtig. Auch in den hier in den Antworten sonst so gegebenen Formen ist beides richtig. Beispiel:

> Die Richterin hat ihn freigesprochen / schuldiggesprochen.
>   Die Richterin hat ihn frei/schuldig gesprochen.

Es gibt eine Verwendung der Verben sprechen und machen/tun, welche da lautet:

Jemanden/Etwas *[Adverb]* sprechen. Jemandem/Etwas *[Adverb]* tun.

> Sie hat ihn schuldig gesprochen. Er hat ihr gut getan.

Als stärkere Qualifizierung der Verben können diese Wörter im Deutschen zusammengeschrieben werden:

> Sie hat ihn schuldiggesprochen. Er hat ihr gutgetan.

Richtig ist beides, es ist nur so, dass die grammatikalische Richtigkeit von einer gefühlsmäßigen (unberechtigten) Unrichtigkeit überlagert wird, da „schuldigsprechen“ im Perfekt aufgrund der Velarplosivdopplung (-gg-) in einem langen Wort (fünf Silben) das Gefühl einer Wortfuge erzeugt.

Die Darstellung des Duden, man schreibe etwas nur zusammen, falls hieraus ein neuer Begriff entstünde, ist so nicht richtig; es handelt sich immer noch um dieselben Worte, im Fall der „freisprechenden Richterin“ ist ebenso wie im Fall der „frei sprechenden Richterin“ erst aus dem Kontext ersichtlich, was gemeint ist, und die Assoziation, bei einer häufig „frei sprechenden Richterin“ handele es sich automatisch um eine, die häufig ohne Manuskript spreche, liegt schlicht daran, dass die Bedeutung von „(als) frei sprechen“ = „zum Freien erklären“ weniger medienpräsent ist als andere Bedeutungsformen. Denn jemand, der „frei spricht“, spricht ohne Zwang (eines Textes) und jemand, der „als frei gesprochen wird“, wird vom Zwange befreit.